# Issue with wp_schedule_event()

Tags: wp-cron, events

I am trying to set up an event on a custom interval that will grab new posts from an Instagram search and create them as wordpress posts. I had the code working on its own page, and now I am trying to schedule it to happen automatically.

I have also installed Wp Crontroller to ensure the event is being recognized by Wordpress (which it is) but I cannot seem to get the code to run (nor can I figure out how to debug it.

```
add_action( 'wp', 'create_schedule' );

function create_schedule() {
  wp_schedule_event(time(), 'quarter_hour', 'ig_fetch_start');
  update_option('test', 'Close!');
}

add_action('ig_fetch_start','ig_fetch_new_posts');

function ig_fetch_new_posts() {
  update_option('test', 'Fired');
  // Run function
}
```

The option update is in there just to see if the event is firing. Wordpress simple never seems to make it to the ig_fetch_new_posts function.

Comment: Are you sure the schedule `quarter_hour` is available?

Comment: Yes, This is a schedule I have created earlier in functions.php. The schedule is also correctly displaying in the WP Crontroller dashboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to schedule the event differently. In your approach, you hook to `wp` to schedule the event, meaning that it is called everytime WordPress is called, setting your option back.

I am not quite sure if the schedule is postponed or if you create multiple schedules this way, but it is not correct.

You should check if this event is scheduled (using `wp_next_scheduled()`), and only schedule if this function returns false, to avoid multiple entries/postponing issues.

I would also use two different options to check if the functions get called, because due to the architecture of this system, as soon as your scheduled function is fired, the value changes - only to be overwritten when you next call WordPress, as no event is scheduled.

I also added a time to the optionvalue, to check when it was registered. I always like to know stuff like that on debugging.

The script (including the registration of a new schedule) would look something like this:

```
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'f711_add_quarter_hour_cron_schedule' );
function f711_add_quarter_hour_cron_schedule( $schedules ) {
    $schedules['quarter_hour'] = array(
        'interval' => 900, // Time in seconds
        'display'  => __( 'Quarter Hour' ),
    );

    return $schedules;
}

if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'ig_fetch_new_posts_hook' ) ) { // check if function is scheduled
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'quarter_hour', 'ig_fetch_new_posts_hook' ); // if not, schedule it
    update_option('test_scheduled', 'scheduled' . time() ); // set your scheduleoption to scheduled
}

add_action( 'ig_fetch_new_posts_hook', 'ig_fetch_new_posts' ); // define the hook for the schedule

function ig_fetch_new_posts() { // your updatemagic
    update_option('test_fired', 'Fired' . time() );
    // Run function
}
```

Comment: The option it not being changed to 'Scheduled' which leads me to believe the event is properly scheduled, but it is also not updating to 'Fired', so something still seems to be off with the event hook. Is there a way to clear the scheduled event so I can start it fresh?

Comment: You can use `wp_clear_scheduled_hook( 'ig_fetch_new_posts' )` to achieve that. Also, where did you put your code? You can just place it in your `functions.php`, no need to add further actions. I usually check if everything works with the [Crony Cronjob Manager Plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/crony/). You can also remove scheduled events there.

Comment: All this is in functions.php.
Looking through the docs for [wp_schedule_event()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event), it seems that the hook is supposed to be an action, not a function. Could that be what is missing here?

Comment: oh silly me, forgot that. updated the answer.

Comment: I feel like I'm getting close. I installed Crony Cronjob Manager, and cleared out all of my old events (from pervious testing) and ensured my timezone was correct. The next run time of my event seems to be correct, but it still isn't firing the event. (the option is not getting updated)

Comment: I'm thinking the issue now is how I trigger the cron jobs. This needs to run regardless of whether the site is visited or not, so I am using a technique similar to [this](http://tommcfarlin.com/wordpress-cron-jobs/)

It seems that my server-side cron job made to ping wp-cron.php is not running. I have tried accessing it directly, and it still does not trigger the events.

Comment: Please create a new question for this, and do not forget to provide debug information, as this question is resolved. Try running it with built-In `wp-cron` first.

Comment: Wait, does your option get updated if you call the function directly?

Comment: Just used `add_action('init', 'ig_fetch_new_posts');` and it ran just fine, so I would say yes, the function calling is resolved.